# Sandcastle 'SHFB Visual Studio Extension Package' project - How to build only on 'Release'?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, build, msbuild, sandcastle

I am using the Sandcastle 'SHFB Visual Studio Extension Package' - which creates a Sandcastle project inside the Visual Studio solution. The integration is nice, but it automatically builds the documentation project every time I do a build. I'd like it to only build the help project for a "Release" build, but unlike other VS projects, the properties options for the Sandcastle documentation project have the "Configuration" and "Platform" selectors disabled.

I have looked at the other property options, but nothing seems to allow selecting options for WHEN the project should be built. Online searches have turned up instructions for specifying the build-on-release-only option when using the standalone SHFB gui tool, or if using the MSBuild command line for a non-integrated sandcastle project (via a different project's build events), but nothing about configuring an included project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having come across this just the other day:

Go to configuration manager for your solution. Uncheck the `build` option for your documentation project for all but the "release" configuration.

Comment: Thanks, Jon, That worked :-) I had forgotten about the solution-wide configuration manager!